# Sinonimo de Tag bootstrap

Tags: suporte, tags

Reparei que temos tags para [bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap) e [twitter-bootstrap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap).

Grande parte das pergunta da primeira são relacionadas a segunda tag. Alguém com reputação suficiente poderia criar um sinônimo?

Comment: Estou tentando resolver isto, mas além da comunidade não entender a proposta ainda ninguem colabora com opiniões sobre o que fazer, note que bootstrap é diferente de twitter-bootstrap, o bootstrap pode se referir a varias coisas, este termo é mais antigo na informatica que o framework CSS citado. **Veja isto:** [Qual deve ser o uso correto da tag “bootstrap”?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4718/3635) ... Eu criei várias sugestões, mas poucos ligaram, ou opinaram e a que teve mais votos foi uma solução inviável para o sistema :/ ... Pelo jeito vai continuar as moscas.

Comment: Se importa se eu marcar como duplicata?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento colocar uma descrição na tag poderia ajudar... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/bootstrap/info

Comment: eu talvez estava pensando em eliminar a [tag:bootstrap] e usar apenas tags com prefixo, veja um exemplo no SOen, a tag composer virou sinomo de composer-php, isso porque outras tecnologias que usam o mesmo nome.